# Can't get working ip check code(single rule is working, multiple not)

Tags: php, arrays, tor

need to forward all Tor users away from my page, with checking ip in tor lists.
Single check was working with ipv4 but not working with ipv6 and multiple list checking.
Can't understand where i get error.
code:

```
$torip = file("https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$torexits = file("https://lists.fissionrelays.net/tor/exits-ipv6.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$tornode = file("https://lists.fissionrelays.net/tor/relays-ipv6.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (in_array($client_ip, $torip)){ 
header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); 
}
if (in_array($client_ip, $tornode)){
header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); 
}
if (in_array($client_ip, $torexits)){
header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); 
}
```

was trying different way's like

```
if(in_array($client_ip, $torip) or in_array($client_ip, $tornode) or in_array($client_ip, $torexits))
```

and if ... elseif .. elseif

same can get inside via tor with ip that is in list and can't understand where is the problem.
Thank You to All for help.

UDP:
code part

```
$tornode = file("https://lists.fissionrelays.net/tor/relays-ipv6.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (in_array($client_ip, $tornode)){
header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
die();  
}
```

is working 100% - question - how to add other list in checking in the right way?

Comment: what is the result of `$torip $tornode $torexits`? is it array? if its array why don't u loop through it and make validation before header location

Comment: @AtoliGaming - `file()` will always return an array with each line as an element (or false if it for some error occurs). And why would they need to iterate through them? They are using `in_array()` to check if the client's IP is in each array.

Comment: I'm sorry I get your target wrong, so you only need to check if the array exists. what is the result of the ipv6 and multiple list checking?

Comment: we need to forward all tor users(users with ip from lists) away from our web page

Comment: When you test the code, is the client-ip actually in any of those lists of IP addresses? That is, is your code working correctly and perhaps the lists are not correct?

Comment: yep, checking current ip from tor browser, checking ip - is in list, openning page - not forwarding. have no ideas, anymore how to fix

Comment: This isn't just an issue with some previous output to the browser causing the header redirect to fail, is it? Only needs to be a single white space. And really you should `exit()` after a header redirect, otherwise PHP will continue and display the rest of the page before redirecting.

Comment: something like
`
if (in_array($client_ip, $torip)){ 
header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); 
die();
}
`
?

Comment: Slightly O/T, but personally I'd retrieve the first list, then check if my IP is in it and redirect. If not, then get the second list and check again and redirect, and then try the third list. There's no point getting the second and third list if your IP is in the first one.

Comment: Exactly where is the code failing when you debug? Is it failing to retrieve the list that your IP is in, or is it failing to find it using `in_array()`, or is it failing to redirect?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure using `die()` would be correct as that generally signifies an error occurred, but that code with `exit()` instead might do it.

Comment: failing to redirect, ip is in list (checked manually) but not forwarding away

Comment: so, ok, code part
`
$tornode = file("https://lists.fissionrelays.net/tor/relays-ipv6.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (in_array($client_ip, $tornode)){
header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
die();  
}
`
is working and forwarding, how to add in the right way other two list check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here...

1. I hope you aren't downloading those lists every time someone visits your page. You should be caching the results of the list downloads for a short time rather than constantly downloading.
2. The only fissionrelays list you need is `exits.txt`. As outlined at https://fissionrelays.net/lists, exits.txt contains IPv4 & IPv6 exit nodes. Download that instead of exits-ipv6.txt and relays-ipv6.txt.
3. It is incorrect to block Tor relays that are not exits. Hits from a relay IP *is not* Tor traffic. For example, I run a guard relay at home that does not allow exit traffic. Its IP appears in the relay list, but it does not permit any Tor exit traffic so any hits from this IP is not coming from Tor.

If you want to use multiple lists, that's fine. I would suggest the following steps to meet your needs:

```
1. Download & combine all lists every 10+ minutes
2. De-duplicate and sort the list
3. Save to a file
4. Write a function to search the cached file.
```

For 1-3, you could use https://gitlab.com/fissionrelays/lists/-/blob/master/tor.php which is a downloader provided by fission relays to download their lists. It sorts as well.

IF your lists are sorted correctly, you can binary search the list for better results, but this is more advanced and not necessary.

Hint, when downloading lists, don't use `file()` to download as arrays. Use `file_get_contents()` instead, and append each list onto the other. Once all lists are downloaded and combined, process them into an array (skipping dupes), and then sort the list.

Here's a binary search function you can use to search the **sorted** list quicker.

```
/**
 * Perform binary search of a sorted array.
 * Credit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#39115
 *
 * Tested by [VigilanTor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/vigilantor/) for accuracy and efficiency
 *
 * @param string $needle String to search for
 * @param array $haystack Array to search within
 * @return boolean|number false if not found, or index if found
 */
protected function arrayBinarySearch($needle, $haystack)
{
    $high = count($haystack);
    $low = 0;

    while ($high - $low > 1){
        $probe = ($high + $low) / 2;
        if ($haystack[$probe] < $needle){
            $low = $probe;
        } else{
            $high = $probe;
        }
    }

    if ($high == count($haystack) || $haystack[$high] != $needle) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $high;
    }
}
```

Additionally, make sure to call `exit()` after sending a header(Location) redirect since you want to terminate the request and redirect immediately without running additional PHP code.

```
if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
    header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
    exit; // Redirect now and don't run any further PHP code
}
```

Lastly, if you want to assume all Tor traffic is "bad" that's fine. Consider an error message instead of silently redirecting traffic away without explanation which is bad user-experience. Many people use Tor for casual browsing, so you're effectively booting these users from your site with no reason given.

Comment: Thank You a lot, for Your answer. And separate Thank You for explaining.

Comment: Very welcome!  Good luck & feel free to comment back if you have more questions about it. Thank you for accepting the answer.